# how to use this middieware "express-debug" in Express 4.x

Tags: node.js, express

official show very brief introduction

https://github.com/devoidfury/express-debug

after i setup simple `app.js`, how to do debug?

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
require('express-debug')(app,{});
app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.send("Hello world!");
});
app.listen(3000);
```

the official screenshot shows there should be some html file, but where to get it? can anyone help with simple introduction for initial setup?

Comment: Just go to `http://localhost:3000/express-debug`: *"If your application doesn't serve HTML, no worries, a standalone express-debug panel is mounted at `/express-debug`."*

Comment: thank you. i can see now. but it is just a static web page and show some name/values, i don't know how to use it for debugging.

Comment: Well you don't currently have anything to debug, as you only have a single route that just returns plain text. It might be a bit more useful if you actually had something non-trivial.